# How to wrap int column around instead of overflow

Tags: mysql, integer-overflow

Suppose a column of type `unsigned int`. Since 4294967295 is the largest unsigned integer, this query will fail with a overflow error:

```
update mytable set intcolumn = intcolumn + 1;
```

How could I achieve that instead of overflowing, `4294967295 + 1` will become `0` (zero) ?

More generally, by adding any integer, I would just like the integer to wrap around zero instead of overflowing.

I just found out that before mysql 5.5.5, integer silently wrapped around. Only 5.5.5 and above throw an error.

Comment: `update mytable set intcolumn = CASE WHEN intcolumn = 4294967295 THEN 0 ELSE  intcolumn + 1 END;` Anyway why do you reinvent autoincrement?

Comment: That's an idea, but it is not general enough. What if I would add an arbitrary integer ?

Comment: Then it will be incremented by 1. The point is reinventing SEQUENCE/IDENTITY/AUTO_INCREMENT causes more problems than solves.

Comment: And it is not for autoincrement at all. If it were, wrapping around of zero would result in inconsistent references.

Comment: Struggling to wrap my head around why this would be necessary.  Since you're adding any integer at all to it, you might look into a `TRIGGER` to handle this.  Also, if you added more than 1 to the max value would you always want it to be 0 or would you expect the new value to be 0 + the amount greater than 1 you were adding?

Answer (score 1):

update  mytable set intcolumn CASE intcolumn WHEN < 4294967295 then intcolumn + 1 WHEN > 4294967295 then 0

Comment: This only answers the question if I add 1. It does not work for other values to be added.

Comment: same idea `update mytable set intcolumn CASE intcolumn WHEN < 4294967295 - valuetoadd then intcolumn + valuetoadd WHEN > 4294967295 - valuetoadd  then 0`